# Horizontal scrollbar on profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There's a horizontal scrollbar on [my profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/423/felix) (and any other profile, for that matter). Using Chrome on Ubuntu.

[image: unicorn on my profile]

Comment: I also see this scrollbar, in Chrome 11.0.696.34 *and* in Firefox 3.0.6 on Linux. I also see a scrollbar on AU, but not on beta sites, TCS, English or the trilogy.

Comment: Yes, on AU and both sites' metas. Do you also get the unicorn?

Comment: @Gilles Do you still see this? I assume it was fixed in the profile redesign

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I think whatever code was generating this extra scroll bar disappeared with the profile redesign. Toolocalized away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed with the [new profile design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119841/new-user-profile-add-new-first-tab-with-simpler-design); I no longer see the scroll bar in Chrome or Firefox